# Integrated R/markdown/pandoc bibliographies from multiple sources?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, bibliography, citations

Seems like a simple problem: I have an assembled bibliography from pubmed in medline xml format. This works well with pandoc-citeproc to format citations and produce a list of references at the end of the document. I now want to integrate citations from R packages I am using and produce a unified bibliography in pandoc (via pandoc-citeproc).

pandoc-citeproc will write yaml and json bibliographies from my medline xml.  I'm ok with a (possibly manual) merge of R and medline citations before running pandoc.  But I don't see anything in citation() nor pandoc-citeproc that will transform to a medline and citation() output to common format that can be used to create the unified bibliography.

Thanks for any pointers you have.

Comment: I don't know pandoc-citeproc.  Can it handle mixed medline and BibTeX input?  If so, toBIbtex(citation(...)) would get you partway there.  Or can it convert medline to BibTeX?   Note that you do have to do some manual editing on the toBibtex entry.

Comment: Thanks and yes, the ability for pandoc to process different reference formats in the 'compiling'  step was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I used the bibtex package to write R citations to a file

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(plyr)
   library(limma)
   library(bibtex)
   write.bib( c('bibtex', 'ggplot2', 'plyr', 'Biobase', 'limma'), file "R.citations.bib" )
   ```
2. pandoc accepts multiple --bibliography arguments. Importantly, if bibliography filename suffixes are recognized, you can use different bibliography formats (.medline is the ncbi's xml format) and pandoc seems to put everything together:

   ```
   pandoc --bibliography bib.medline --bibliography R.citations.bib file.md -o file.docx
   ```